# How do I enable turning off monitor in notebook with Windows?

Tags: laptop, display, windows-10, power-management

I have Dell Inspiron 14r laptop which is dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04. I noticed something:

In Linux, when you lower the brightness to the minimum, your monitor turns off.
But in Windows, you just get a low brightness configuration.

This made me realize that my monitor can be turned off, but I don't know how I could do this in Windows.

Can anyone help me in this?

Config:

- Dell Inspiron 14r
- Windows 10
- NVidia GeForce FT 740M v10.18.13.5540
- Intel HD Graphics Family v10.18.15.4256

Answer (score 1):

Click start. 
Go to control panel. 
Click or search for power settings. 
You will see power options. By default it is in "balanced" mode. 
The text is clickable.

A pop up opens.

Here you will see various options for the monitor both - battery and plugged in. Just play around here.

You may also install a freeware called screenOff (ver 1.1). It's an executable 10 kb or so file. Copy the extracted file to your task-bar. Click its icon to turn off monitor. 
Press the space bar or move the mouse to turn it on again.